# Hiding NoData values of a raster in MapServer

Tags: raster, mapserver, nodata, rgb, mapfile

In a MapServer NoData value pixels can be hide by using the following code inlcusion in a mapfile:

```
`PROCESSING 'BANDS=3,2,1'`
```

Now I have raster with multiple combinations of NoData Values other than "RGB:000".
I have tried with combinations like `OFFSITE 15 20 106` but its not reflecting in the output. What is the way to offsite the NoData Values of multiple combinations.